# Gametes produced after single and double cross overs

Tags: genetics, homework, recombination, genetic-linkage

A female genotype, shown as abc / +++ produces 100 meiotic
tetrads. Among these, 68 showed no cross over (NCO) events; 20 showed
single crossover (SCO1) between a and b; 10 showed single crossover
between b and c (SCO2) and 2 showed a double crossover (DCO) between a
and b and between b and c. Of the 400 gametes produced, how many will be
of the following types? Fill your answers in the table. ([Source](https://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/olympiads/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/inbo2014-Q.pdf))

[image]

According to me, the answers should be,

A. $68\times4=272$

B. $20\times4=80$

C. $10\times4=40$

D. $2\times4=8$

However, the answers are $336, 40, 20, 4$ respectively. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not taking into account that crossovers happen at the **four-chromatid stage** and between **cromatids**. Take a look at the following picture<sup>1</sup>:

[image: Crossing over]

I suggest you draw down all the crossover events:

[image: Crossovers]

Now count the number of gametes that will be formed:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{(+++) and (abc)} &= 4\times 68+2\times20 + 2\times10 + 2\times 2=\mathbf{336} \\
\text{(+bc) and (a++)} &= 2\times20 = \mathbf{40} \\
\text{(ab+) and (++c)} &= 2\times10 = \mathbf{20} \\
\text{(a+c) and (+b+)} &= 2\times 2 = \mathbf{4} \\
\end{align}
$$

---

1. *Introduction to Genetic Analysis 11th Edition*, W. H. Freeman and Company, 2015.